# Подключить STM32F103C8Tx к питанию от батарейки?

Tags: stm32

Как подключить батарейку 3.6V 1800 мАч к STM32F103C8Tx? Не к пинам же? И нужны ли какие-либо доп. модули, ибо я видел где-то модули защиты\зарядки какие-то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для аккумулятора, обязательно нужна схема контроля заряда/разряда, иначе в лучшем случае, он быстро придет в негодность, в худшем - устроит пожар.

Для самодельщиков типичным вариантом является связка из контроллера заряда батареи и стабилизатора.

Контроллер заряда на базе TP4056:

[image: TP4056]

Стабилизатор лучше всего поставить [импульсный](http://easyelectronics.ru/istochniki-pitaniya-chast-2.html) (для экономии энергии). Я использую микросхему MC34063 и плату собственной конструкции - работает надежно и стабильно.

Comment: На плате уже есть стабилизатор с 5V до 3.3V. Значит, можно просто подключать контроллер заряда + батарейку, и всё будет работать?

Comment: Можно подключить, да.

Comment: @user425739 Если схема в целом будет работать при пониженном напряжении (2.5В) то можно и напрямую, желательно через защиту от переразряда аккумулятора.